# Why does pthread_cond_wait() not block when not linked with "-lpthread"?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, glibc, condition-variable

I'm learning about `pthread_cond_t` and wrote the following code intended to block forever at the `pthread_cond_wait()`:

```
// main.cpp
// Intentionally blocks forever.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <pthread.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  pthread_cond_t cond;

  if ( pthread_cond_init( &cond, NULL ) )
  {
    std::cout << "pthread_cond_init() failed: " << errno << "(" << strerror( errno ) << ")" << std::endl;
  }

  pthread_mutex_t mutex;

  if ( pthread_mutex_init( &mutex, NULL ) )
  {
    std::cout << "pthread_mutex_init() failed: " << errno << "(" << strerror( errno ) << ")" << std::endl;
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
  pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );

  pthread_cond_destroy( &cond );
  return 0;
}
```

When I first compiled/executed this program, the executable *did not* hang - it exited:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.out 
> // <-- Note: returned to bash prompt
```

Next I tried linking against `libpthread` - and *now* the executable hung, as expected:

```
>g++ -g main.cpp -lpthread && ./a.out 
^C
> // <-- Needed to send SIGINT to terminate process
```

I was actually expecting to hit a link error for the required `pthread` functions; why did I not encounter one when I did not explicitly link against `libpthread`?

This question may be rendered moot by the answer to the above, but when compiling without the explicit link the `libpthread`, why did the resulting binary "skip over" or ignore the `pthead_cond_wait()`? Is there some default do-nothing implementation for pthread functions in glibc or somewhere?

Comment: I think we'll have to investigate in this to get why: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_cond_wait.c.html

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: launch with "strace -f ./a.out" and see what happened, or debug with gdb.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The question is related to a C function. The example code that uses this C function is written in C++ but this is not the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some glibc functions need locking when your process is multithreaded.
To avoid dragging in the libpthread dependency everytime because of that, glibc uses weakrefs to refer to a bunch of pthread functionality. If it detects the functionality is not available (which won't cause a linker error because of the weakref solution) it will default those ops to no-ops (which is just fine because if you don't have pthreads, you can't be multithreaded and locking isn't needed).
The upshot of this solution is the behavior you're getting.

Comment: Wao ! stucked with the same problem, this saved my life !